# Embedding of a Riemann surface by Riemann-Roch

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces

[This](https://www.math.columbia.edu/%7Ewarner/notes/AlgGeomSemTalk.pdf) online notes, page 10 reads that we can prove the existence of holomorphic embedding into $\mathbb{P}^n$ of a Riemann surface by RR theorem, but I have no idea how to use it. Does anyone have an explanation? 
(I guess it's related to the criterion considering certain linear systems of line bundles over the Riemann surface. I have read the results on Hartshorne's book once, but totally unfamiliar with that.)

Moreover, does the method work for the case of higher dimensions?

Comment: @user10354138 Sorry, that should be page 10.

Comment: Very quickly, for a curve $X$, the map $\phi_D\colon X\to\lvert D\rvert=\mathbb{P}(L(D))$ sending each point $x$ to $(f_1(x):\dots:f_n(x))$ for a choice of basis $f_1,\dots,f_n$ of $L(D)$ defines an embedding iff $\ell(D-P-Q)=\ell(D)-2$ for all $P,Q\in X$.  But by Riemann-Roch, for all divisors $D$ with $\deg D>2g$, we have $\deg D>\deg (D-P-Q)>2g-2=\deg K_X$ and hence $\ell(D)=1-g+\deg D$, $\ell(D-P-Q)=1-g+\deg(D-P-Q)=\ell(D)-2$ and so we have an embedding into some $\mathbb{P}^n$.

Comment: @user10354138 Thanks for your hint... I forgot the criterion $l(D-P-Q)=l(D)-2$ ...